# ERROR in ./src/components/pages/table/Table.js 9:0-30 Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase

i was imported like this way that db **import {db} from 'firebase';** but i got above error, in my fire base-config took like this way**=>**

```js
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
   authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
   databaseURL:process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_BASE_URL,
   projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
   storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
   messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
   appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  };
const app =initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const users = collection(db, "users");
const auth = getAuth(app);
 export  {db,auth,getDocs,users,addDoc };
```

Can you please give solution for my question?

Answer (score 0):

I had made mistake above db module didn't properly imported that db moudule path, so that's why above error throughs from that db module.**just i had fixed my issue like this way to import db module.**

1.***import {db} from '../../../firebase';***